# Разбить ListView на страницы

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Друзья, добрый день!

Есть pet-проект персонального блога.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы посты блога не выводились всем скопом на одной странице, а подразделялись на отдельные страницы ("1, 2, 3... n").

Не подскажете, как это можно было бы реализовать?

**models.py**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
data = models.DateField(max_length=30, auto_now_add=True)
text = models.TextField(max_length=8000)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-data']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**views.py**:

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-data')
    template_name = "main/posts_list.html"
    context_object_name = "post"
```

**posts_list.html**:

```
{% block body %}

{% for post in object_list reversed %}
    <div class="news_container">
        <a href="{% url 'main:post_details' post.pk %}"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
        <p class="news_data"><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i> {{ post.data }}</p>
        <p>{% if post.text|wordcount > 56 %}
            {{ post.text|safe|truncatewords:50 }}
            <p class="read_more_button">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'main:post_details' post.pk %}';"
                        type="button" class="light-button">
                    {% translate 'Читать далее' %}
                </button>
            </p>
            {% else %}
                {{ post.text }}
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="black_line">
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортируйте класс Paginator в views.py.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
```

Обновите BlogListView чтобы ипользовать пагинацию. Вместо того, чтобы просто передавать все посты, вы используйте Paginator для разбиения постов на страницы. views.py должен выглядеть в итоге вот так:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

class BlogListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-data')
    template_name = "main/posts_list.html"
    context_object_name = "post"
    paginate_by = 10  # Указываем количество постов на одной странице

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        paginator = Paginator(self.get_queryset(), self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

Теперь вам нужно перебирать posts, а не object_lis., и выводить ссылки на страницы. Вот, должно выглядеть так:

```
{% block body %}

{% for post in posts %}
    <!-- Ваш код для вывода постов -->
    <!-- ... -->
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if posts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; первая</a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">предыдущая</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current-page">{{ posts.number }}</span>

        {% if posts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">следующая</a>
            <a href="?page={{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}">последняя &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

В принципе должно заработать.

Comment: Всё работает, огромное спасибо! А можно ли сделать так, чтобы на первой странице отображались последние 5 постов? (Другими словами, чтобы пагинация осуществлялась от более новых постов к более давним).

Comment: Всё, уже сделал сам. Ещё раз большое спасибо!